# HTTP GET/POST Request with Twitch API and JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, xmlhttprequest, twitch

So first I'm new to ajax and JSON http get request, etc. I try to use the new Twitch API to get information about streamers.

```
var token = $.ajax({
   'url' : 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/oauth2/token?client_id=XXX&client_secret=XXX&grant_type=client_credentials',
   'type' : 'POST',
   'success' : function(data) {
     console.log(data.access_token);
     localStorage.setItem('token', data.access_token)
   }
});

var test = $.ajax({
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')},
    'url' : 'https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users?login=nightbot',
    'type' : 'GET',
    'success' : function(data) {
      console.log(data); // returns an obj with an data array, length 1
      console.log(data[0]); // undefined
      console.log(data.display_name); // undefined
      console.log(JSON.parse(data)); // syntax error
      console.log(JSON.parse(data[0])); // syntax error
      //$( "#result" ).load( data.display_name ) //to do
    }
});
```

DATA: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcXaE.png

I think that this way is a bit messed up. Is is?

My second problem is, that I can't access the data from the GET REQUEST. The output shows me that there is data but somehow I can't access it and I don't know why.

Comment: where are you passing 'data' property in your ajax?

Comment: Are you aware that both those calls are asynchronous, so the token call won't be complete by the time the test call is made?

Comment: Can you share the content of `data`?

Comment: Please use ajax error function like `error: function (jqXHR, exception) {...}` to know if any error occurred with your ajax calls.

Comment: @archer yes i already know, but i want that i will work somehow and after that solving that problem.

Comment: So is that your problem?  Your question is very unclear.

Comment: @kami1991 I added the answer. Hope it will work as per your expectation. please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The output shows me that there is data but somehow I can't access it and I don't know why

As per the OP statement :

```
console.log(data); // returns an obj with an data array, length 1
```

Hence, to access the array first element you should use below statement.

```
console.log(data.data[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how AJAX call works, the first `$.ajax` call executes a request and immediately the `$.ajax` call is executed and your data within `localStorage` will be inconsistent.

Execute from your first `$.ajax` call the second process `https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users?login=nightbot`.

This way your calls are consistent and will share a consistent data within `localStorage`.

## Twitch `/users` endpoint

According to the Twitch documentation (`/users` endpoint), the response follows this structure:

```
    {
      "data": [
        {
            "_id": 45454
            "display_name": "Ele"
            .
            .
            .
            .
        }
    ]
}
```

**So, you have to access that array as follow:**

```
console.log(data.data[0].display_name);
```

Lool this code snippet, the first `$.ajax` call executes a function called `executeUserProess`.

```
var token = $.ajax({
  'url': 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/oauth2/token?client_id=XXX&client_secret=XXX&grant_type=client_credentials',
  'type': 'POST',
  'success': function(data) {
    console.log(data.access_token);
    localStorage.setItem('token', data.access_token);

    executeUserProess();
  }
});

var executeUserProess = function() {
  var test = $.ajax({
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
    },
    'url': 'https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users?login=nightbot',
    'type': 'GET',
    'success': function(data) {
      console.log(data); // returns an obj with an data array, length 1
      console.log(data.data[0].display_name);
      //$( "#result" ).load( data.display_name ) //to do
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Thats solve one of my problems :). Is this the common way to do so?

Comment: @kami1991 this is one way, but there are others ways, like Promises.